# PHP - Strange IF statement

Tags: php

Today I found a strange if statement that reports true without errors in PHP7. See the example below;

```
<?php
$array = array();

// This is true
if (!is_array($array)['key']) { echo 'test1'; }

// Strangely, this reports false
if (true['key']) { echo 'test2'; }

// This also reports true
if (!(1)['key']) { echo 'test3'; }

// Knowing the statement must be false (!(1)), you would think that false works; it doesn't
if (false['key']) { echo 'test4'; }
```

Can someone explain why it reports test1 and test3 as true when it is clearly faulty code without throwing errors? It did on PHP 5.6 for all statements except the first one (test1).

Comment: When I try this it throws syntax errors beginning with the first `[` Correcting for syntax yields undefined indexes. Is this the actual code?

Comment: Make sure you are using PHP7.0 or later. This is testcode to demonstrate the weird behavior. I do not get errors on PHP7, while I do get errors for the second (!) test in PHP 5.6 or lower.

Comment: `is_array($array)['key']` is NULL. `!NULL` is true,

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've actually copied OP's code, I'm using php 7.1.0RC5 and, uhm, it works fine. Which is odd to say the least. I can't believe one can call indexes on language constructs. Or call indexes on anything that isn't a damn array(or a string as of new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is

```
var_dump(is_array($array)['key'], true['key'], (1)['key'], false['key']);
```

And it is

```
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

And a man string:

> For any of the types integer, float, string, boolean and resource, converting a value to an array results in an array with a single element with index zero and the value of the scalar which was converted. In other words, `(array)$scalarValue` is exactly the same as `array($scalarValue)`.

Comment: Category: [things that should throw a notice/warning](http://atom.smasher.org/wof/word-puzzle.jpg.php?l1=&l2=true%5B%27key%27%5D&l3=&l4=&c=Things+that+should+throw+a+notice)